# WooCommerce how to show product category once on cart page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I need to show products category before  product listing in cart.I need to show products category only once if multiple products of same category have been added in cart.

For example, if user select a product from brand1 and add to cart then add product in cart from brand2. I am trying to changing the code of cart.php template file, but I am not getting any results.

Is this possible in WooCommerce?

Cart will look like this

```
 product name      category       qty    price

 Brand1
 aaa               Brand1         2      50
 bbb               Brand1         1      10

 Brand2 
 test1             Brand2         2      40
 test2             Brand2         1      10 


 Brand 3    
 test11            Brand3         2      40
 test21            Brand3         1      10
```

How to show product category once on cart page?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using? SQL-Server, MySQL, Oracle....

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by get_the_terms function like

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
$product_catz = '';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
$product_catz .= $term->name.',';
}
echo rtrim($product_catz,',');
```

in your cart page